# Update on reboot with init.d

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian, init-script, init.d

I created a script to add a bunch of packages and update the system on a fresh install. Here's the relevant part of my init.d script that is giving me trouble:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          update
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       Update my system
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting update"

    apt-get --assume-yes update &&
    apt-get --assume-yes dist-upgrade

    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start" >&2
    exit 2
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I made the script executable and registered it with `sudo update-rc.d update defaults`. When I check on it after a reboot with `sudo service update status`, I get all of the package repositories failing to resolve:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://.../Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving '...'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and the `init.d` script ends here with `code=exited`. However, adding a `sleep 10` to the script before running the `apt` commands fixes my issue. I would have thought that adding `$network` to my `# Required-Start` list would have fixed this issue by itself. Is there a better way of dealing with this issue?

I'm running this on `Raspian Jessie 2016-03-18` if that makes a difference, but I have a feeling it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

adding one or two more services to start after the network service as part of the requirement before running your update service should add more productive delay rather than adding a sleep 10 in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that still seems like a workaround to me. Since `sleep` doesn't actually use any resources while it's running, this would achieve about the same thing while adding complexity.

Comment: `sleep` is sensible way to do it if you don't have anymore service awaiting to get started. you can try to adjust your waiting time to a lower value as the problem is clearly on network initialization stage.

Comment: Right, but I'm wondering why it isn't already waiting for the network initialization since it has the `# Required-Start: $network` directive.